# Find out what  the current page is in JSF 1.2

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I need to figure out what the current page is I'm on using a bean.

Something like getting the current form id from facesContext and compare it to a const string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()`.

Be aware that this is the current JSF view that's being processed. If you use forwarding techniques via a Servlet or do navigation without a redirect, this is not necessarily the same as what the user's address bar is showing.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed tnx

Comment: in EL: #{view.viewId}